# Is there a way to set the primary key of an auto incremented column

Tags: mysql

```
create table foo (id PK, value integer)

insert into foo (1, 1)
insert into foo (2, 2)
insert into foo (3, 3)
```

If I remove all the inserted values and re-insert the statements

1. The values don't start with 1, even though my script says 1. How do I control this?
2. If I inserted a primary key by mistake is there a way to update the primary key alone.

i.e.

```
insert into foo (4, 4)
insert into foo (6, 6)
```

I would want to update key=6 to key=5. Would that be possible?

Comment: If the value you insert doesn't exist in the table, you _can_ specify the value for the auto_increment column, even if it comes before the current auto_increment value. In other words, if you execute what you have above, then delete all rows, then execute again, it will insert the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

ALTER TABLE Table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 99; -- whatever

alter table Table_name drop primary key;
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first part, you can set the auto-increment value with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to use `UPDATE` statement if desired value doesn't exist in table.